# Can you load a JSP page via an ajax?

Tags: ajax, jsp

Want to execute some JSP code via an ajax call:

We're doing

```
jQuery.get('myfile.jsp');
```

Shouldn't that work?

The jsp file is like this:

```
<jsp:scriptlet> session.removeAttribute </jsp:scriptlet>
```

I can tell it's not "firing" because the attribute still exists.

Comment: Page doesn't seem to have been loaded. Will the JSP page load and function correctly when requested by this method?

Comment: It should work. What are you doing with the output? Are you just doing .get() and expecting something else to happen?

Comment: ahem , what do mean? you can load response from ajax and then you have to parse the response yourself. its upto you how you handle it. if you want response in to load in some div better use jquery.load()

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work.

I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't work", but a few things to try:

- Check your Net tab to see if the request is actually going through.
- Are you getting any errors on the server side (check the server logs)?
- Try using `jQuery.ajax` with an `error` callback to see if you're getting any other errors.